# How do I attach an object to an animated Fps Model?

Tags: animation, objects, tracking, parent

My goal was to have a rectangular prism under an animated first person shooter arm and track its transformation without it warping.
[image]

This is the arm that I am using. As you can see there is no armatures to animate the arms, but there are vertex groups. I didn't animate this, this is exported from a game.

The red rectangular prism is what I am trying to attach under the arm.
[image]

The idea I had in mind was to put them together and parent each other with automatic weights.(I got this from this tutorial: https://youtu.be/FiaXBDsk4M0?t=193)

Things didn't go its way and this was my result.
[image]
Although it has tracked the , the rectangle warped itself.

I have been having trouble for a LONG while and it led me here trying to get some help.

I need the rectangular prism to be stiff(not warped) and follow the transformations of one of the arms. Anyone have an idea to do this?